# Эффективны ли лямбды?

Tags: java, лямбда-выражение

Если использовать лямбда выражения в [java](/questions/tagged/java), к примеру в Stream API, то программы будут работать быстрее?

Я просто слышал, что они ускоряют работу программы. Если да, тогда в каких случаях они не дают выигрыша в производительности?

Comment: Если тебе нужно единожды присвоить куда то функцию, используй лямбда. Если тебе нужно использовать её многократно в разных местах, не используй лямбда.

Comment: Нет не будут. Более того на горячих участках кода у вас может быть просадка из-за аллоцирования объектов и генерации мусора.

Comment: @Nofate насколько я понял механизм лямбд в java, они "разворачиваются" на этапе компиляции, а не в рантайме, в анонимные классы, но то, что мусорного кода больше, чем делать это вручную, полностью согласен (или я неправильно понял у вас слово "генерация")

Comment: лямбды - это синтетический сахар и как всякий сахар, служит для удобства программиста, а не оптимизации работы, которой как раз и жертвуют за это удобство и о ускорении при их использовании речи точно не идет

Comment: @pavlofff, да само собой на этапе компиляции. Если лямбда "чистая" - на выходе будет статический метод. Если она захватывает внешнее состояние - анонимный класс.